# Special summands in $(x+h)^{100}$

Tags: number-theory

We have $(x+h)^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{100}{k}x^{100-k}h^k$.

So there is just one summand without an $h$ and also just one summand with exactly two $h$, isn't it?

And why is $x^3-x$ resp. $x^5-x$ divisible by $3$ resp. $5$?

Comment: "with exactly two $h$" ?

Comment: Do you know what $\binom{n}{k}$ means? It may answer your question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm assuming they mean one term with $h$, one term with $h^2$, etc.

Comment: @Mark: I know but I want the OP to realize that what he wrote is meaningless.

Comment: @Mark You're right :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, sorry!

Comment: @user455297 I see you are a logician and like to answer questions such as "why is the sky blue?" with "yes" and "no".

Comment: Also, you're asking two different questions. They should be in separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x-1)(x+1)$

$x^3 -x$ is the product of three consecutive numbers $x-1,\;x,\;x+1$

One at least of them is always even, exactly one is a multiple of $3$ thus not only $x^3-x$ is divisible by $3$ but it is always divisible by $6$

$x^5-x$ can be factored as $x(x^4-1)=x(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1) x (x+1) \left(x^2+1\right)$

If one of $x-1$ or $x$ or $x+1$ is a multiple of $5$ we are done. If not what can happen? $x+2$ is a multiple of $5$, that is $x+2=5k$ and $x=5k-2$

Let's plug this value in $x^2+1$. We get $(5k-2)^2+1=25k^2-20k+5=5(5k^2-4k+1)$ and this shows that $x^2+1$ is a multiple of $5$.

The last possibility is that $x+3$ is a multiple of $5$. Then, again, we have $x+3=5h$ that is $x=5h-3$. Substitute again in $x^2+1$ to get $(5h-3)^2+1=25h^2-30h+10=5(5h^2-6h+2)$ so again $x^2+1$ is a multiple of $5$

BTW: one of the numbers is a multiple of $5$ and one is even, 
thus $x^5-x$ is always a multiple of $10$

Hope this helps :)

PS

There are no other possibilities because wrt to divisibility by  $5$  both $x+4$ and $x-1$ behave in the same way. It's cyclical

Comment: That helps, thank you! Is there a generelisation like $x^n-x$ is divisible by $n$?

Comment: Don't know let's try with a random number like $\quad x^7-x\quad$
And try also $\quad x^6-x^6$... I begin to see a pattern and you?

Comment: Well we have $x^{n}-1=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$. I guess this helps but I don't see how yet, do you?

Comment: Try numeric examples. By the way, this is the path of the greatest: Fermat, Euler, Gauss. The "experiment" before, and the proof after

Comment: I do not see any pattern

Comment: $(x^7-x)\to \{126,2184,16380,78120,\ldots\}$  are ALL multiple of $7$ while $(x^9-x)\to \{510,19680,262140,1953120,10077690,\ldots\}$ almost none is divisible by $9$. What is the characteristic of $2,\;5,\;7$ and not $9$?

Comment: You mean this holds only for prime numbers?